# Веб разработка, в каком направлении развиваться и что необходимо учитывать на фрилансе

Tags: веб-программирование

я веб-разработчик, уже пару лет занимаюсь этим, в моем арсенале стандартный набор инструментов для создания полноценного проекта: html, css, js, php.

Буквально до этого года (2019) я жутко не любил фреймворки и препроцессы, относился предвзято и с большим отторжением, но единственный нормальный заказ подарил опыт в создании приложения с фреймворком на Laravel. Конечно же сейчас не понимаю как вообще что-то мог делать без этого.

Вопрос заключается в следующем, что необходимо изучать и что необходимо иметь при себе, чтобы найти заказ на фрилансе? Я перебрал несколько десятков страниц на разных источников и не нашел работы для себя как таковой, а если и находил, то там было свыше 100 заявок, из которых я был в самом конце.

Заметил что практически везде есть движки в проекте, в особенности: wordpress, openCart, magento.

Что касается вёрстки, то в большинстве случаев просят делать всё на bootstrap.

Я никогда не использовал ранее bootstrap, потому-чтл всегда справлялся с вёрсткой сам и просто не было необходимости тащить за собой этот компонент.

Я хочу узнать, стоит ли впадать в крайности и изучать популярные движки и компоненты, какие есть плюсы и минусы подобной разработки, на каких знаниях уехали в жищнь фриланса именно вы, ну и стоило ли оно того в целом?

p.s. не знаю насколько правильно и корректна создана тема, но вроде как форум соответствующий и вопрос тоже.

Comment: >wordpress, openCart, magento - не фреймворки. Все зависит от того, чего вы хотите. Либо клепать мелкие сайтики, либо более-менее крупные проекты. Но запомните - клиенту наплевать на чем сделан его сайт.

Comment: @DaemonHK , прошу прощения за свою ошибку, даже не имел представления что это не фреймворки. Я просто хотел нормально работать как и все остальные люди, но смотря вакансии и их требования, сам понимаю что могу сделать эту же задачу по своему, но заказчик ставит условие в необходимости наличия wordpress/etc. На выходе получается все не так как хотелось, я - разработчик, который может сделать любой проект, просто не в состоянии даже найти работу. Здесь люди явно опытнее, поэтому хотел узнать у вас, какие есть варианты развития событий, стоит ли изучать движок, какие есть общее советы..

Comment: С таким вопросом вам на бы на тостер какой-нибудь, там бы вам быстро показали что вы никто, а они дядьки, делающие по 80К на простой верстке)) А если серьезно, цель фриланса - не бегать от проекта к проекту, а найти свою нишу и 3-4 нормальных заказчиков. Будете мелочиться, быстро выдохнитесь.

Comment: @DaemonHK , спасибо за информацию, просто хотел узнать у здешних людей об этом деле.. На самом деле, я не стремлюсь искать много работы, мне бы и хватило найти человека который загрузит работай и просто развивать и поддерживать его проект, но такого практически нет, а может я не там и ищу..